# How to call a program on the server using MeteorJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, server

Currently, I am building an application in Meteor. The application is based on transforming application information in an XML format. And then run a program on the XML created on the server. After that read the xml file created and bring it to a new collection.
On the other hand, personally I run on my linux machine manually:

```
(*) ./ myprogram -xml = myOutput.xml -out = myout.xml -timelimit = 300
```

myOutput.xml where is the generated file.
myout is the file generated by the program.
And timelimit is the maximum runtime of the program.
  So far I have done the following:
Once all income, build a xml file with the values stored in my collections. This was performed as follows:
(1) server startup declare the use of fs

```
Meteor.startup (function () {
     fs = Npm.require ('fs');
// ...
}
```

-In My methods I build the file with its corresponding information

```
Meteor.methods ({
transform: function () {
fs.createWriteStream wstream = var ('myOutput.xml');
...
//....operations over the collections
...
wstream.end ();
... (2) ...
},

});
```

All good so (2). The file is either created.
After (2), I need to make program implementation as in (*). The program depends on the xml file built and an outlet.
After contextualize my problem my questions are:
How I can run the program on the server using the file created? And
What I locate the executable folder "myprogram" to use it?

Comment: can't you just use `exec` form the native `child_process` node package, and just keep all files in the absolute path `/tmp/something`?

Comment: Sorry I missed investigate a little deeper. Now, I learned to use child_process.execFile that solves my problem.